# Does elysia cron need to be executed through Drush cron?

Tags: drush, cron

I am trying to understand how Elysia Cron works. If I execute the cron through a curl/wget requests, will the elysia cron still run normally without risking timeouts? Are there any advantages to running it through Drush rather than curl/wget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module page is fairly clear ...

> For the basic install you only need to enable the module and Elysia
>   Cron will be up and running.
>
> You can stop here if you don't need a great precision over task
>   execution and you don't have to execute a task more often than once an
>   hour. For example, if you need only the "Once a day", "Once a week" or
>   "Once a month" schedule rules the basic install is fine. (For D6 users
>   that want to stop here: you should have installed Drupal crontab as
>   described in Drupal INSTALL guide).
>
> However to get the full potential out of elysia cron and have the full
>   control over you tasks a further step is needed: you need to configure
>   the system crontab to execute drupal cron every minute. Follow the
>   Drupal guide about this: http://drupal.org/cron The only difference is
>   that you should use the "* * * * *" rule part instead of "0 * * * *"
>   or "45 * * * *" as described in the guide.

[Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a server thing, not a Drupal thing. [Hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) is a nice PHP interface to stuffing custom tasks into the file `http://www.mysite.com/cron.php` which Drupal's Poor Man's cron or [ElysiaCron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) can use to run your tasks.

As the above notes -- if you just need daily runs, weekly runs, monthly runs -- simply enable the barebones Elysia or Drupal cron. For more fine grained control over cron tasks they recommend a system crontab entry that polls Drupal cron every minute. Elysia's task management logic checks what tasks it has to do in X timeperiod every minute (whats Done, what is to begin, whats running, etc). This is the power of Elysia cron and also [UltimateCron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron).

Whenever a browser hits `cron.php` you are subject to timeouts -- even if programming attempts to avoid it (such as the Batch API, which *can* sometimes timeout and fail -- eg what happens when your webserver (Apache) is under load and the next `cron.php` call is never successfully handled?).

By running via Drush you are 100% free of worrying about webserver timeouts -- because its now a server side PHP script which may run indefinately.

- 1 advantage of running through Drush is you can pipe output from your
  cron tasks (there shouldnt really be any) to a custom file.

You can invoke a Cron run directly using Drush via:
`drush cron` for all options to Drush cron see `drush help cron`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I thought too. I am afraid of timeout. Also configuring the cron for elysia cron requires hitting sites/modules/contrib/elysia_cron/cron.php instead of normal drupal cron.php. In any case, your answer verify my understanding that elysia cron logic is independent from how the cron setup.

Comment: Elysa cron is invoked with `drush elysia-cron`.

Comment: Yes, if you are doing the cron using drush but not with curl/wget.